# Mysql: select from information_schema.STATISTICS hanging or slow? never saw a result

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I'm trying to check statistics with
    select from information_schema.STATISTICS
The query never ends. I have to stop it.

I checked innodb_stats_on_metadata=0 like in this post [Solving INFORMATION_SCHEMA slowness](https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/12/23/solving-information_schema-slowness/), it was already set to 0.

Any idea?
I have more or less 20K tables and mysql 5.6.
Could this also give performance problem?

Answer (score 0):

20K tables means opening 20K files on the system.  This takes minutes on the typical server.  How long did you wait?

20K tables *often* means poor schema design.

BTW, the slowness will be solved in 8.0, when the .frm files are moved into InnoDB tables.  Many I_S queries will be a hundred times as fast.

Comment: it's a multi tenant application with one DB per each tenant. That makes 200 tables per 100 tenants, All in the same MySql instance

Comment: Let's step back -- Why are you preforming the I_S select?